# Could we derive the mass of neutrinos using a supernova and gravitational lensing?

Tags: mass, neutrinos, supernova, gravitational-lensing

There are a lot of questions on this site about getting neutrino mass from timing the arrival of neutrinos vs light from a supernova, I believe this is different.

If we see a galaxy that is gravitationally lensed and we monitor it long enough shouldn't we see the lensing of neutrinos from a supernova? If so would it be in a different area due to its mass and therefore derive it?

Comment: That their mass is nonzero is already taken care of by the fact they undergo oscillations. Do you mean to determine mass directly?

Comment: Similar to https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/0004-637X/828/2/112 ?

Comment: @tratticus correct, I edited the question

Comment: are you referring to angular resolution as a discriminator?

Comment: [Neutrino detectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_detector) generally don't have fine angular resolution. IceCube can resolve down to a couple of degrees, but I suspect you need much finer resolution for your proposal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not realistically. For a gravitational lens, you obviously need a lensing object such as a galaxy in between you and the supernova. So, we are talking supernovas that are at cosmological distances, way beyond our own Local Group. For such large distances, the 1/distance$^2$ suppression of the neutrino flux means that we do not expect to see a signal in any current or forseeable-future neutrino detector.

Further, you would not expect to observe a larger angular diameter because the point spread function (the angular resolution) of neutrino detectors is poor at best (for Super-K or Hyper-K) or non-existent (for all others). Then you say let's use the different travel time along the lensed path, sure, but how do you measure that, because any light will be lensed in the same way, so there is no reference.

tl;dr: nope.

Comment: Fair, a lot of unknown variables with a fair amount of assumptions. I also didn't consider the angular resolution needed from neutrino detectors. I guess currently we don't have the tech but it seems like something achievable in the future.

Comment: hehe, yes, but only for /some/ definition of "future"...